What is the maximum x for getdate()-x in SQL SSMS?
This question is more out of curiosity rather than troubleshooting.
What is the furthest we can go back using getdate()-x in SQL (even if it is unrealistic e.g. 10000 years). I'm looking for its bound if any.
Also, if we were to use something like dateadd(year,- x, getdate()) could we go as far back or even further back than what getdate()-x allows?
I don't currently have access to SQL, and can't find the answer anywhere. I'm just wondering if there is such a bound how large can x be before the query fails.
Thank you!

datediff(day, '1753-01-01', getdate()) is the highest value of x that will succeed .  99123 as of today. getdate() is a datetime and the lowest bound for that is 1753-01-01

This is why my sql always errors when I try to query the number of days that have passes since Prince William of Orange became Knight of Garter

@JNevill yeah, i hate when that happens
